# Displaying BufferedImage in Vaadin

Tags: vaadin, bufferedimage, chdk

I want to display an BufferedImage that is returned by some API ( a Java Library for Canon Hack Development Kit) in my Vaadin Application without saving it to the file system. Is that somehow possible? It doesn't seem to be much of a hassle in swing but I have found no way to do it in Vaadin so far.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is perfectly possible with Vaadin using a `com.vaadin.server.StreamResource`. A `StreamResource` provides the data of some `InputStream` and can be used anywhere a `com.vaadin.server.Resource` is expected (i.e. links, images, icons...).

The following example method creates a `StreamResource` for a `BufferedImage` on the fly:

```
 private StreamResource createStreamResource() {
    return new StreamResource(new StreamSource() {
        @Override
        public InputStream getStream() {
            String text = "Date: " + DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance(DateFormat.FULL, DateFormat.MEDIUM).format(new Date());

            BufferedImage bi = new BufferedImage(370, 30,
                    BufferedImage.TYPE_3BYTE_BGR);
            bi.getGraphics().drawChars(text.toCharArray(), 0,
                    text.length(), 10, 20);

            try {
                ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                ImageIO.write(bi, "png", bos);
                return new ByteArrayInputStream(bos.toByteArray());
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                return null;
            }
        }
    }, "dateImage.png");
}
```

This can be used with an `com.vaadin.ui.Image` as follows:

```
Image image = new Image("", createStreamResource());
layout.addComponent(image);
```

Refer to the Vaadin Docs about [Stream Resources](https://vaadin.com/docs/-/part/framework/application/application-resources.html#application.resources.stream) for more information.

Comment: This seems to be a good way to generate a PNG File from the Buffered Image once - but it does save the file somewhere on the filesystem - even if i restart the tomcat the image returned by this method is the same. To generate a new image I need to change the "file name" at the end of the method. 
I sure could change the filename to a timestamp-string but I'm afraid I will fill my file system with "old" images.

Comment: That's correct, the approach shown in my answer will create a new in-memory image every time it is requested, which answers the original question. Of course, you could put each image into a cache on the file system and serve it from there if it already exists. This opens a whole new range of problems pertaining to caches (cache eviction, etc.), so you're advised to use an existing cache implementation for that.

Comment: BTW, the name at the end of the `StreamResource` constructor is the resource's name which happens to be used as file name if you choose to download the resource. In my code example, no data will be written to the file system.